# SQL: Randomly select one group from groups defined by frequency

Tags: sql, mysql, random, group-by

I have a mysql-table with 2 columns. Column 1 is "bedid" (integer). Column 2 is "rartid" (integer). For each rartid there is one or more associated bedid's. For each bedid there are one or more associated rartid's. Now I want to randomly select one of these groups from the group of rartid's that occur in at least two rows. I would like to get the group with 2 columns (rartid,bedid). What is the appropriate SQL syntax?

This is an example:

table:

| bedid | rartid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 33 |
| 3 | 33 |
| 4 | 44 |
| 5 | 55 |
| 6 | 55 |
| 7 | 22 |
| 3 | 44 |
| 2 | 66 |
| 8 | 55 |

Desired results:

| bedid | rartid |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 33 |
| 3 | 33 |

or

| bedid | rartid |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 44 |
| 3 | 44 |

or

| bedid | rartid |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 55 |
| 6 | 55 |
| 8 | 55 |

Comment: does the number of bedids for a rartid determine how likely it should be to be chosen?  or should all rartids (with two or more bedids) have an equal chance?

Comment: They should all have the same chance regardless of the number of lines a rartid is in. The answer of nbk ist great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This would produce 1 rarid randonly, and then display all occurrences

```
CREATE TABLE val
    (`bedid` int, `rartid` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO val
    (`bedid`, `rartid`)
VALUES
    (1, 11),
    (2, 33),
    (3, 33),
    (4, 44),
    (5, 55),
    (6, 55),
    (7, 22),
    (3, 44),
    (2, 66),
    (8, 55)
;
```

> ```
> Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT `bedid`,v1.`rartid` FROM 
  val v1 JOIN (SELECT `rartid` FROM val GROUP BY `rartid` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) v2
  WHERE v1.`rartid` = v2.`rartid`
```

| bedid | rartid |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 33 |
| 3 | 33 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RsJdk8_y)

Comment: this doesn't restrict to just rartids that occur 2 or more times